# how to login into salesforce using facebook or twitter credentials (social login)

Tags: api, social-content

I need to implement "social login" feature into my salesforce application. Kindly give a step by step example which shows how can achieve this.

I need to put a facebook,twitter and google icon beside user_id/password area of salesforce login. Purpose is to be able to enter into salesforce using any of the social login credentials.

An urgent and detailed response will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Devesh

The easiest way to implement social login is through a provider like [Janrain](http://janrain.com/) which will make it easier for a customer to signup to your system using Social Sign On.

Pat Patterson (@metadaddy) [has a good blog post on developerforce](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/01/social-single-sign-on-authentication-providers-in-spring-12.html) about this which is a good starting point for you as well as it goes through the use cases and options available, including setup.